# How do I sort a list of file names in the Windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, sorting, cmd

The following code displays file names in a directory and sub-directories and puts the results into `results.txt`. I am having trouble sorting the list. Where do I put the sort option?

```
for /r %i in (*) do @echo %~ni >> results.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do the sort later, once the results are written to the text file. Add a second line to your batch file reading:

```
sort results.txt
```

The results will be written back to results.txt. Alternatively you can get it to go faster by using

```
sort /O:NewResults.txt results.txt
```

And getting it to write to a different file.

Comment: can be done with a single line: `(for /r %i in (*) do @echo %~ni)|sort /o results.txt` (Note: no colon after `/O`). Only one file gets written, so it should be faster.

Comment: @Stephan you should add this as a separate answer as to me it is the best and simplest answer

Comment: @crazjo: ok, to help others who stumble over this question. Although I guess it doesn't help the asker, as the question is quite old.

Answer (score 4):

Use the dir command:

```
dir /ON /B >> results.txt
```

The /ON sorts by name.

The /B returns in "Bare" (name only) format.

If you add /S it will recurse all sub-directories, but will include the file path.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a single line:

```
(for /r %i in (*) do @echo %~ni)|sort /o results.txt
```

writing the output to a file with `sort` switch `/o` is faster than redirecting `sort > file.txt`

Only one file gets written, so it should be even faster.

(Note: this is command line syntax. For use in a batchfile, replace each `%i` with `%%i`)